# Woocommerce update custom order query for 3.0

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've got some code which outputs a list of completed orders to the [sales-list] shortcode in my functions.php. It was working perfectly before the 3.0 update of Woocommerce, but has since stopped working due to (I assume) the new CRUD classes in 3.0.

Question is: how do I adapt this to work with the new classes? Or if that isn't the issue, what else may have changed?

Here's the code:

```
/* Sales List */
function saleslist_shortcode() {
  global $woocommerce;
  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'shop_order',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'shop_order_status',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => array(
                  'completed'
              )
          )
      )
  );

  $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>

  <div class="sales-list">
  <?php
  while ($loop->have_posts()):
      $loop->the_post();
      $order_id = $loop->post->ID;
      $order    = new WC_Order($order_id); ?>
      <article>
        <h6 class="mtn ptn">Order #<?php echo $order_id; ?> &mdash; <time datetime="<?php the_time('c'); ?>"><?php echo the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></time></h6>
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
              <tbody>
                    <?php echo $order->email_order_items_table( array(
                        'show_sku'      => true,
                        'show_image'    => false,
                        'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
                        'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
                        'sent_to_admin' => true
                    ) ); ?>
              </tbody>
          </table>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>   
      </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
  <?php
}

add_shortcode( 'sales-list', 'saleslist_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Check this function "$order->email_order_items_table"

Comment: That method is deprecated but still exists. I believe the problem is that taxonomies aren't used to determine order status. It's been post status for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably start with changing the `post_type` parameter to `"post_type" => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )`. And dropping the tax query as order status is handled by "post status".

I think I would recommend switching to [`wc_get_orders()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/505813403e39387fdf4d6e6fc9c9a14c4bd6f9ae/includes/wc-order-functions.php#L49). Here's my best guess for now. Keep in mind that this will have a fatal error if you aren't using WC3.0... ie: it is not backcompatible.

```
/* Sales List */
function saleslist_shortcode() {

  $args = array(
        'limit' => -1,
        'status' => array( 'wc-completed' ),
        'type' => array( 'shop_order' )
  );

  $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

  ob_start();

  if( $orders ){ ?>

    <div class="sales-list">

      <?php foreach( $orders as $order ){ ?>

        <article>

          <h6 class="mtn ptn"><?php printf( __( 'Order #%s', 'your-plugin' ), $order->get_order_number() ); ?> <?php printf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', $order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' ), wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?></h6>

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td"><?php _e( 'Product', 'your-plugin' ); ?></th>
                        <th class="td"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'your-plugin' ); ?></th>
                        <th class="td"><?php _e( 'Price', 'your-plugin' ); ?></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php echo wc_get_email_order_items( $order, array(
                        'show_sku'      => false,
                        'show_image'    => false,
                        'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
                        'plain_text'    => false,
                        'sent_to_admin' => false,
                    ) ); ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </article>

      <?php } ?>

    </div>
  <?php }

  return ob_get_clean();

}
add_shortcode( 'sales-list', 'saleslist_shortcode' );
```